# Apart from hardware, what affects the performance in terms of number of concurrent users?

Tags: performance, appfog, blitz++

I'm developing an API and want to (of course) optimize performance in terms of number of concurrent users.

I have run some tests using Blitz (my app is on Appfog, PHP, 512MB, 1 instance) according to those tests my API can handle 11 concurrent users before response times get too high (>1000 ms).

For me it is surprisingly low. I can add more RAM and instances to improve the results but I suspect that my code could be smarter.

I did some tests, always with same hardware config. Result is number of concurrent users before exceeding 1000 ms in response time.

- Using my actual API (with db-queries) --> 11 users
- Using script that just outputs text (minimum processing) --> 40 users
- Using script with sleep(2) function to simulate long response time --> 52 users (before exceeding (2000 + 1000 ms)
- Using a memory intensive script (building data with for-loop): 95 users

I really don't see any correlation in the results (each test has been run many times with similar results). The more processing for the script - the more concurrent users?

What is that affects the number concurrent users (apart from hardware config)?

Comment: This looks like db may be your bottleneck. Did you measure the execution time of your SQL statements?

Comment: Also, in general the number of concurrent users that can be handled by a web application is influenced by a very large number of factors. Can you narrow down your question to be more specific to your concrete problem?

Comment: I have measured DB-queries and started using memcache. It improved the response time quite a lot, but not the number of concurrent users. That's why I made som tests, and those results doesn't make any sense to me. They tell me that if I lower execution time and memory usage does not necessarily results in more concurrent users. So basically I want to understand what metrics I should focus on in order to increase my performance for concurrent users.

Comment: Using sleep() to simulate longer execution time probably does not work the way you think it does. This will pause execution of the current thread, but it will not increase CPU load. This means that the throughput (which is what you are measuring as "concurrent users") does not change in terms of cpu load. Can you give a little more explanation as to how you interpret the individual results above in order to reach the conclusion that "[...] lower execution time and memory usage does not necessarily results in more concurrent users."?

Comment: Ok, that explains part of my results! Then I am only confused by test 2 and test 4. Test 2 is just one echo statement, and test 4 is a for-loop (x100000) that does some calculations and then echo a message. Perhaps such for-loop is not so CPU intensive(?), but I am puzzled that test 4 performs twice better! I would expect it to be about the same as test2 or worse.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand a bit more. To conclude, in my code I should focus on minimizing I/O and as a result I will hopefully be able to handle more concurrent users?

Comment: No, at this point I/O is just the main suspect. What you need to do is find evidence for what is actually happening and then use that evidence to guide your optimization effort. This means that you will have to somehow determine what part of your code contributes which part of the total request time. To achieve this, you can use a profiler or instrument your code with additional measurement code. I'd recommend timing individual database requests as a starting point. Also, if you show us your code we may be able to suggest what to investigate specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally there are two aspects you should think of:

- bottlenecks like database or external APIs. You are as slow as the slowest component
- look for locks that turn your concurrent code into sequential. See: [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

The second point is related to the first one. Database or whatever you use in your code might be internally synchronized or might not cope well with concurrency.

Comment: I am using MongoLab and MemCachier. They are both Addons to Appfog, so I access them remotely (all services are run at AWS-EU-West), could this be a bottleneck? Would you define them as "external"? And if they are bottlenecks, would that affect the CPU usage? I mean, if the database (on MongoLab, that is another server) is slow to respond, doesn't that just affect the total response time and not the load on my app (=concurrent users performance)?

Comment: @luttkens: you are right that *response time* != *throughput*. But e.g. if database is under heavy load, it'll become slow to respond with growing number of connections. The only 100% way is to add some profiling/logging and find out which parts of your architecture take most of the time.

Comment: Eventually it turned out to be the database the was the bottleneck! Since the thread on the webserver (PHP) lives as long as the database-query (and takes up memory), the slow response from the database made query, after query to add upp.